# What does “w/” mean?

Tags: meaning, abbreviations

The B strings tuned w/ low E 7th fret harmonic-(6th string,7th fret).

Comment: Interestingly, the _w/_ is one of the very few things that _do_ mean something to me in that sentence. I'm guessing it's about a musical instrument, and I am musically... challenged :P

Comment: Please have a look in a [dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/w/) before asking. Thank you.

Comment: Cool, I wouldn't have thought a letter with punctuation would be defined in the dictionary

Comment: Surprised, this is marked as off-topic.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The shorthand **w/** is used to mean *with*.

> 2 pieces toast w/ gravy

Is a shorter way of writing "Two pieces of toast with gravy."

> The B strings tuned w/ low E 7th fret harmonic-(6th string,7th fret).

means "The B strings tuned **with** low E, 7th fret harmonic . . ."

*Edited to add:* As Denis de Bernardy correctly notes in the comment below, **w/o** means the opposite: *without*.

Comment: Commenting to add for completeness: and **w/o** means *without*.

Comment: The harmonic on the E string corresponding to a B is actually found a tiny touch higher (toward the bridge) than right above the 7th fret, on a standard 12-tone equal temperament guitar. It's only 2 cents difference, but if you tune your guitar entirely by harmonics, it adds up. You'll get a Pythagorean ditone instead of a 12-tET major third between G and B, for example. If you try to tune using harmonic thirds rather than only harmonic fifths, you'll wind up wildly off from the pitches at the frets. Just so you know.